# swapping limit and series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, almost-everywhere

Consider i.i.d non negative integer valued random variables $Z_t$ with $Y_t= \sum_{k=1}^t Z_k$
and the partial sum
$$s_n:=\sum\limits_{j=c}^{\infty} P(Y_{j+1-c}=j) F^{n+c-j} 1_{\{j \leq c+n\}}$$ with

$$F^{n+c-j}:= E\left[\left(1- \frac{Y_{n+c-j}}{n+c-j}\right)\cdot 1_{\{Y_{n+c-j} \leq n+c-j \}}\right]  $$

I know $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F^{n+c-j}=1-z$$ for $z<1$ a.s.

I want to prove: $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = (1-z) \sum\limits_{j=c}^{\infty} P(Y_{j+1-c}=j)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, Dominated Convergence Theorem would work fine in your case. Thing is I'm still concerned about the convergence of your limit object, especially the convergence of the series
$$ \sum_{j=c}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}( Y_{m+1-c} =m ) $$
(Though the presence of that convergence is not important to for our limit proof)

Let :
$$G_j(n) = F^{n+c-j} 1_{ j \le n+c}$$

According to the definition $G_m$,  $0 \le G_j \le 1$ and $\lim_m G_m= (1-z) $ pointwise.

Also, for the sake of clarity, we define another object $\mu$ which is a measure on $\mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$\mu(\{m\}) = \mathbb{P}( Y_{j+1-c} =j ) \text{ when }m \ge c$$
So :
$$ s_n= \int G_m d\mu$$
and
$$  \text{your limit object is }\int \lim G_m \mu $$

Now, let's treat your problem in different cases:

- If $\mu( \mathbb{N})<+\infty$, then $(1-z) \in L^1(\mu)$ hence by Dominated Convergence Theorem, we imply our desired result.
- If $\mu( \mathbb{N})= +\infty$, then by Fatou we have:
  $$\liminf s_n \ge \int \liminf G_m d\mu =+\infty  $$
  and note that $(1-z)\mu( \mathbb{N})$ is also equal to $+\infty$, so we still have our conclusion.

**Discussion** It'd be nice if you can expend my knowledge by having me informed of the convergence of the initial series when $\mathbb{E}(Z_1^2)=+\infty$

Comment: I am not sure if Tannery holds because I have convergence only a.s.

Comment: I have taken a look at your argument. I deem that you haven't checked the condition for Tannery's carefully. What is $M_k$ ? Is your $\sum M_k <+\infty$?

Comment: I could take:$ P(Y_{j+1-c}=j)1_{\{j \leq c+n\}}$ as $M_j$

Comment: Well, you see, $M_k$ should be independent of $n$, while yours is dependent of it

Comment: Take $P(Y_{j+1-c}=j) $as $M_j$. I can leave the indicator out.

Comment: At that point, as I've shown in my initial comments, we are not sure $ \sum P(Y_{j+1-c}=j )< \infty$

Comment: If you can help me show that that sum converges without condition on $E(Z_1^2)$ , it would already be nice

Comment: Yeah, if it is finite, you can do that.

Comment: Thank you. But does the limit swapping apply only a.s. since I have only a.s. convergence of $a_j(n)$

Comment: Your convergence is pointwise, like any real sequence, not a.s . So you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: You mean $a_j(n)$ Why is that?

Comment: There is no randomness in those terms.

Comment: F is  not random?

Comment: You have calculated expectation, which cancels out all randomness.

Comment: Well, IMHO, it does not

Comment: Not really, I guess I've done your initial question, I'll leave you with the rest.

Comment: Yes sorry. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: I appreciate it very much.

Comment: No problem. Sincerely.

Comment: @ Paresseux Nguyen: Sorry for the question. But the limit of $F^n =1-z$ for $n \infty$, is only 1-z almost surely?

Comment: @Sarah: Dear Sarah, your observation is not really true. By the same remark that I gave you earlier, your $F^n$ is now a real number, not a random variable. So, it is a convergence in the usual sense of real sequences.

Comment: No, it makes no sense. I have $$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} F^{n+c-j}=1-z$$ a.s. I have no randomness, which is clear since the expected value is already taken. I do not unterstand how we get from an convergence a.s. to a pointwise convergence. In both cases is E taken :(

Comment: Okay, I think you're confused a little bit. So, inside your expectation, you have a sequence of random variables that converges  a.s to $1-z$. (You can even notice that, that sequence is bounded) . Then after that, we take the expectation of that sequences, (so randomness disappears here) and thanks to DCT, your a.s convergence is now transfered to a convergece of real sequence.

Comment: I thought DCT only states that I have convergence a.s. That is my error in thinking. Ok I got for real now. Thank you again :)